# Filter django admin according to polymorphic

Tags: python, django

Trying to get django-polymorphic to work in the admin.  I have a number of ChildModels inheriting from BaseModel, but clicking on any of them in the Django admin all lead to a listing of all BaseModel objects, which is useless to me.  I've tried both redefining the queryset and including the list_filter as the documentation (outdated, I've learned) suggests, but neither seems to have any effect.

```
class BaseModelChildAdmin(PolymorphicChildModelAdmin):

    base_model = BaseModel
    show_in_index = False
    form = BaseModelForm


class ChildModelAdmin(BaseModelChildAdmin):
    exclude = ('asset_url', 'asset_file')
    base_model = ChildModel
    show_in_index = True

    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = ChildModel.objects.all()
        return qs

class BaseModelAdmin(PolymorphicParentModelAdmin):
    base_model = BaseModel
    child_models = [(ChildModel, ChildModelAdmin)]

    list_filter = (PolymorphicChildModelFilter,)
```

Comment: As I said in one of your previous questions, you need to normalize your models. If you did you wouldn't be going on these wild goose chases

Comment: @e4c5 Thank you but that's not an option for me.  I am not the lead developer here and I've worked here for less than two weeks.  Although your advice may be good it's not really helpful here on what I feel is still a good question that could be of use to other people.